# Suggestions for a computer vision teaching module in R

Tags: computer-vision

I'm teaching an undergrad seminar in machine learning. It's quite basic: kNN, tree-based models, neural nets, etc. For the last module I ask the students what they'd like to cover and they voted for a computer vision application. Any ideas? I've done [eigenfaces](https://towardsdatascience.com/eigenfaces-recovering-humans-from-ghosts-17606c328184#:%7E:text=Eigenfaces%20is%20a%20method%20that,reducing%20computation%20and%20space%20complexity.) before which was fun but I used the Olivetti faces data and it was a little dated.